# What is the difference between Micro-controller and Micro-Processor?

Tags: microcontroller, microprocessor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between a microcontroller and a microprocessor?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/whats-the-difference-between-a-microcontroller-and-a-microprocessor)

I am new to the micro-controllers and yet I don’t know much about that. While reading a book about micro controllers I come the Question that "What is the fundamental difference between Micro-Controllers and Micro-Processors?”, because AFAIK both can do the same job. And Intel micro processor series starts form Intel 8086, which is a microcontroller.