# Difference between Zilog Z80 and Z84?

Tags: microprocessor

I was looking into Farnell.com catalog for Zilog Z80 microprocessor and I found only [Z84C00](http://uk.farnell.com/zilog/z84c0010peg/ic-cpu-z80-10mhz-84c00-dip40/dp/1081891).

What is the difference between Z80 and Z84? Is there any? And what is the difference between Z84C00, Z84C20 and Z84C30?

Comment: Download the data sheets, they will have all the information you need.

Comment: I wanted to add links to the datasheets, but they seem to be scanned documents, so it looks at least like "not recommended for new designs". Possible not recommended at all...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The original **Z80** was produced in the older NMOS technology, the **Z84C00** is its CMOS version. The CMOS version is able to run at higher clock frequencies.
The Z80C00 is the CPU, the **Z84C20** is a PIO (Parallel I/O) device, and the **Z80C30** a CTC (Counter/Timer Circuit). Nowadays all microcontrollers include functions like PIO and CTC on chip. This is the main [difference between a microprocessor and a microcontroller](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/whats-the-difference-between-a-microcontroller-and-a-microprocessor).